# Visual C++ "List of Libraries" meaning

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile a c++ source code file from the DXC competition.

The instructions are:

To compile any of the C++ examples (or a DA written in C++) under Windows, MS 
Visual C++ 8.0 (2005) is required. Make sure to add %DXC_HOME%\Lib and 
%DXC_HOME%\Include to your library and header search paths respectively, and add 
dxcApi.lib to your list of libraries (or dxcApid.lib if compiling in debug 
mode).

I added Lib and the Include libraries to the library and search paths and it imported them. What I didn't understand is the meaning of the second step: "*add dxcApi.lib to your list of libraries*" - what does it mean?

Without this step I'm getting linker errors, such as:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: _*thiscall
>   Dxc::CandidateSet::~CandidateSet(void)"
>   (*_imp_??1CandidateSet@Dxc@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public:
>   void __thiscall ExampleDA::sendDiagnosis(void)"
>   (?sendDiagnosis@ExampleDA@@QAEXXZ)    D:\Dropbox\Work\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\DXC11\DXC11\ExampleDA.obj   DXC11

I'm stuck with this problem for quite some time now and I'm desperate for help!
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the specific `lib` file to the libraries list, so that the linker can search it for the symbols you're missing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The task says to add that particular .lib to the list of libraries *that get linked to your code*. Without saying that this library should be linked, the implementation for the functions defined in its headers is not available to the linker and you get that unresolved external symbol.

In VS, you can add something to the linked libraries list either through a [`#pragma comment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or in the project settings:

```
// at the top of main.cpp, preferrably
#pragma comment(lib, "the_lib_name.lib") // .lib optional
```

You can have different libraries for debug and release with simply surrounding the `#pragma comment` in an `#if` block:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG // release
#pragma comment(lib, "the_lib_name.lib")
#else // debug
#pragma comment(lib, "the_lib_named.lib") // most debug libraries end with a 'd'
#endif
```

And for the project settings you can do so with

```
[Project] -> <Project Name> Properties (or Alt-F7) -> Configuration Properties
    -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies
```

Just add `the_lib_name.lib` at the front (followed by either a space or a semi-colon `;`). Make sure you add the correct library for the active project configuration (debug / release).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Interesting, thanks for letting me know. I always only saw the list with semi-colons. Amended the answer accordingly.

Comment: I prefer the #pragma approach myself.